# How to Write Junit for this Basket1 class include scanner in MAIN class

Tags: java, junit

I have a main class Basket1 and Item for setter and getter, Please help me in writing the Junit for this project. I have to write a JUNIT to test my project. The JUnit test function can be a Scan test or getter setter one and also the sum of the Item.

```
package Basket;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

class Basket1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Item> Cart = new ArrayList<Item>();
        Item item;
        String itemName;
        double itemPrice;
        int quantity;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        double totalPrice = 0.0;
        double sum = 0.0;

        String keepShopping = "y";

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of the item: ");
            itemName = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the unit price: ");

            Double n1 = 0.0;
            boolean bError = true;
            while (bError) {
                if (scan.hasNextDouble())
                    n1 = scan.nextDouble();
                else {
                    scan.next();
                    System.out.print("Please Enter valid Price");
                    continue;
                }

                bError = false;
            }
            itemPrice = n1;
            System.out.print("Enter the quantity: ");

            int n2 = 0;
            boolean tError = true;
            while (tError) {
                if (scan.hasNextInt())
                    n2 = scan.nextInt();
                else {
                    scan.next();
                    System.out.print("Please Enter valid Unit");
                    continue;
                }

                tError = false;
            }
            quantity = n2;

            item = new Item(itemName, itemPrice, quantity);
            Cart.add(item);

            for (int i = 0; i < Cart.size(); i++) {
                Item itm = Cart.get(i);
                System.out.println(itm);
            }

            System.out.print("You want to continue? Y/N ");
            scan.nextLine();
            keepShopping = scan.nextLine();
        } while (keepShopping.equals("y"));

        scan.close();
        for (int i = 0; i < Cart.size(); i++) {
            Item itm = Cart.get(i);
            System.out.println(itm);
            totalPrice = itm.getQuantity() * itm.getPrice();
            sum += totalPrice;
        }

        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        System.out.println("The total price is: " + fmt.format(sum));

    }

}


package Basket;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Item {
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;

    public Item(String itemName, double itemPrice, int numPurchased) {
        name = itemName;
        price = itemPrice;
        quantity = numPurchased;
    }

    public String toString() {
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        return (name + "\t" + fmt.format(price) + "\t" + quantity + "\t" + fmt.format(price * quantity));
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your concrete question? Have you tried anything? People here probably won't write the unit tests for you...

Comment: First problem in writing Junit,  is the code is in Main block and second the scanner class is using User input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing your basket code inside the `main()` method you should add a new class `Basket` which has calculation methods like `addItem()` and `getSum()` (along with other methods relevant for the `Basket` class). This new class will not have any user inputs or output messages, just a container for your items and calculations.

When you have such a class you have actually something you can write JUnit tests for. One test method would be "create a new basket, add some times, check that the sum of the items is the same as the expected one". Other tests would be like "throws an exception when the quantity is not positive" or "throws an exception when one argument is `null`".